# register_uninstall_hook() vs uninstall.php - which one is better way to handle plugin uninstallation script?

Tags: plugin-development, uninstallation

today while looking inside WP Codex, I saw two ways to handle plugin uninstall scripts (like deletings, options, data, tables etc.). One way is using `register_uninstall_hook()` and the other is by using the simple `uninstall.php`.

Though the [codex page](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/uninstall-methods/) gives a lot of info about both of them, but it doesn't say what is the advantage of using one over another.

As there are so many WP gurus here, I thought I should ask this question about which option is the better way of handling uninstall script? Using `register_uninstall_hook()` or `uninstall.php`?

Hope somebody will clarify. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The benefit of `uninstall.php`, and the reason that it was introduced, is that it allows you to isolate your uninstallation code from the rest of your plugin's code. This means that your entire plugin doesn't have to be loaded when it is uninstalled. That minimizes the chance that your plugin will inadvertently run code during uninstallation that is only intended to be run when the plugin is active. However, in general, you shouldn't be running arbitrary code in your plugin files anyway, most everything should only run if triggered by a hook.

From the [docs included in the original commit](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/plugin.php?rev=8585#L510):

> The plugin should not run arbitrary code outside of functions, when
>   registering the uninstall hook. In order to run using the hook, the
>   plugin will have to be included, which means that any code laying
>   outside of a function will be run during the uninstall process. The
>   plugin should not hinder the uninstall process.
>
> If the plugin can
>   not be written without running code within the plugin, then the plugin
>   should create a file named 'uninstall.php' in the base plugin
>   folder...

**TL;DR:** Your plugin should really be structured in such a way that it doesn't *have* to use `unisntall.php`, but using it anyway adds extra protection against accidentally running things during uninstall.

Of course, in some cases you may need to load parts of your plugin in order to uninstall it properly anyway. But if you are using `uninstall.php`, including those files will be a conscious decision that you make, so it is harder to mistakenly load some file of your plugin that runs arbitrary code.

The only time that I would use the `register_uninstall_hook()` method would be in a very simple, single-file plugin, where all of the code was encapsulated into a single class.

---

Note that [`uninstall_plugin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/uninstall_plugin/#source) will run the `pre_uninstall_plugin` <strike>and `uninstall_{$plugin_file}`</strike> *[edit: `uninstall_{$plugin_file}` will only run if `register_uninstall_hook()` is used]* action hook regardless of which method you use. (See ticket [#34569](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34569).)

Comment: Awesome answer. Actually I'm working on a new plugin where I've to create options and insert data within wp tables. So, it's my responsibility to clean up the database upon uninstall. So I was thinking which path should I take to run the unregister_settings, delete_option etc. Should I take the uninstall hook way or the uninstall file way. But after reading your answer, I think uninstall file way would be a good option. What do you think?

Comment: @iSaumya Yes, I'd use the uninstall file way, if it were me. The uninstall hook way might be a good fit for very simple single-file plugins where all of the code is encapsulated in a single class. In any other case I'd use the `uninstall.php` file.

Comment: @iSaumya I just realized that I was actually wrong about the `uninstall_{$plugin_file}` hook running for both cases. @the_dramatist is correct that it only runs when `register_uninstall_hook()` is used. However, note that anything wishing to hook into plugin uninstall should probably be using `pre_uninstall_plugin` instead (which does indeed run for both). See [ticket #34569](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34569). So I wouldn't make that a deciding factor in which of these you choose to use.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you want. `register_uninstall_hook()` creates hooks and it executes when the `uninstall` link clicked. That means it actually create a hook which will be called on clicking the uninstall link. Say you developed a plugin and based on that plugin you want to create other plugins and those add on plugins needs to perform operation on based plugin uninstall, then this hook is gonna be useful. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_uninstall_hook/) you'll get a full overview.

And `uninstall.php` is a generic uninstaller for your plugin. It'll fire upon your plugin uninstall. But it does not provide any hook by default.

Look [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/uninstall-methods/) for further information.

Comment: You can put hooks into your uninstall.php too though. The link is the same as in the question. Any reference for your best practice?

Comment: Yea. We can put hooks in `uninstall.php`. But I said it's not provided by default. And for references please have a look on `WordPress Plugin Development Boilerplate` or any boilerplates. Here is the Tom McFarlin's boilerplate link https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate.

And if you want to provide hooks through `uninstall.php`, you can do it. But as the context of his question I preferred the `register_uninstall_hook()`.

Comment: @the_dramatist It is not possible to provide both of these, see the [source of `uninstall_plugin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/uninstall_plugin/#source). The `uninstall.php` file will take precedence, and any uninstall hook will be ignored and the `uninstall_{$plugin_file}` action will not be fired.